# Expand a datatable adding new rows and replacing NA values by group

Tags: r, datatable

I'm trying to expand a datatable based on a column (in below example `Month`) and fill in the empty values by groups (`Group`). Take following example `dt`;

```
set.seed(0)
dt<-data.table(ID=c(1:10),Month=sample(1:10,replace = F),Group=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B",'A','A'))
dt[1:4,":="(Income=rnorm(4),Tax=rnorm(4),Birth=sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2000/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2002/05/01'), by="day"), 4))]
```

I would like to expand the table so that for each `Group` there will be 10 rows such that each row has values for the column `Month` from 1 to 10. Remaining columns (`Income`, `Tax`, `Birth`) should be filled based on the existing rows. NA's should take the values from the most recent 'Month'. So for `Group` A the datatable should have 10 rows as follows (i.e. in total the final datatable should have 10 rows for each group):

```
dt_desired<-data.table(
  ID=rep(1:10),
  Group=rep("A",10),
  Income=c(rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==1]$Income,8),rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==9]$Income,2)),
  Tax=c(rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==1]$Tax,8),rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==9]$Tax,2)),
  Birth=c(rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==1]$Birth,8),rep(dt[Group=='A'&Month==9]$Birth,2))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `data.table::nafill()` cannot process non-numeric columns (yet?), so I had to use `zoo:na.locf()` instead..

```
library( data.table )

#first, create CJ, then perform update join
ans <- CJ( Group = dt$Group, Month = dt$Month, unique = TRUE )[ dt, 
                                                 `:=`( Income = i.Income, Tax = i.Tax, Birth = i.Birth ),
                                                 on = .( Group, Month ) ]
#columns to fill NA's
cols = names(ans)[-(1:2)]
#for locf
ans[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE ), by = Group, .SDcols = cols]
#for  nocb
ans[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE ), by = Group, .SDcols = cols][]
```